# Home Network Two Routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-router

I have a a home network, pretty simple.

```
Internet <-> Modem <-> Router <-> Wireless Devices
```

But the thing is my house is pretty big and that setup is on the on the first floor, but the wireless signal doesn't get to the 2nd floor. I have another router lying around and I thought I could use it to give wireless network to the upper floor.

Is this possible?

If it is I was thinking to do it like this:

```
                                            Router 2 (2nd floor) <-> wireless devices
Internet <-> Modem <-> Router 1 (1st floor) ||
                                            Wireless Devices
```

Is this right? There's a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to connect the two routers with a wire or do it wirelessly? Do both routers support WDS?

Comment: I was thinking using a cable between router 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the router function on the second one and use it just as a wireless access point.  Set it to use the same DSSID as the first one and wire it down to the first one devices will seamlessly switch between the two depending on which has a stronger signal.  Don't use the WAN port.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are compatible with DD-WRT. Flash both of em and make a wireless repeater bridge.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

Exactly what I did. Works like a charm.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but the thing is in the second floor the signal is no very good, that's the problem in the first place. So I think i'll do it wired. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/how-connect-wireless-router-wireless-router-3119.html

or wired network to the second floor to the second router but set the router to obtain dhcp then the second router will act like wifi network switch

http://www.home-network-help.com/router-as-switch.html